# CAS implementation to Oracle APEX

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, cas

I'm trying to implement CAS into APEX application. I have some instruction how to implement it into typical java webapp. I know what to add into the web.xml with all configuration, and this is the easy part. I need to add some dependecies to pom.xml. How i can find it and is this possible to add some dependencies to apex application?

Apex 19.1 is running on tomcat 9 on linux server.

Comment: Dumb curiosity question due to my ignorance: What do you mean when you say "CAS"? Are you implementing user authentication with your Apex app as a Service Provider in the SAML model?  Thanks.

Comment: My Apex app isn't a Service Provider in the SAML model. I wanted to get authentication schema in APEX via existing CAS (based on remote_user).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to add some dependecies to pom.xml. How i can find it and is this possible to add some dependencies to apex application?

I don't suppose Oracle APEX has a `pom.xml` file. So your options are:

1. Add the required dependencies into the tomcat's `lib` directory with the rest of the libraries. This will make them available to all applications deployed in tomcat, including APEX.
2. Add the required dependencies into the APEX under tomcat, which should be at `$TOMCAT_HOME/webapps/<APEX>/WEB-INF/lib`.

I am attaching a screenshot of the dependencies you might need to include in the lib directory. (cas-client-support-saml-xyz is optional). All dependencies can be found on Maven central: https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:org.jasig.cas.client

You also need to make sure APEX is able to recogize the authentication user from the `#request.getRemoteUser()` or the `REMOTE_USER` header. Otherwise, you'll need to add custom code to APEX or other type of configuration to allow for authn to succeed.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Misagh. It helps a lot. In APEX there is something like http header authentication (and i used remote_user).